# How to make a percentage on mysql codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a table with 2 fields. Id_user first field and the second field type of browser, I tried to make a percentage of the total number of users favorite browser based user. after I try to make her its query results do not match a percentage of her, what's wrong?

```
|id_user|   name_item
--------------------------
|   1   |   safari      |
|   2   |   firefox     |
|   3   |   opera mini  |
|   4   |   safari      |
|   5   |   chrome      |   
|   6   |   firefox     |
|   7   |   chrome      |
|   8   |   chrome      |   
|   9   |   firefox     |
|   10  |   firefox     |       
|   11  |   safari      |
|   12  |   opera mini  |
```

which are expected

```
|   safari      |   25% |
|   opera mini  |   17% |
|   firefox     |   33% |
|   chrome      |   25% |
```

Controllers

```
public get_json() {
    $browser = $this->My_model->get_browser();
    foreach($browser as $row)
    {   
        $data['browser'] []= $row['browser'];
        $data['percentage'] []= $row['data_percentage'];
    }       
        header('content-type: application/json');   
        echo json_encode($data);  
}
```

Models

```
function get_browser() {
    $query = $this->db->select('browser, 100 / count(*) as data_percentage')
                      ->from('tb_browser')
                      ->group_by('browser')
                      ->get();      
    return $query->result_array();  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be dividing `COUNT(*)` for each group by the total number of records in the table.  For the latter quantity, you can use the following subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb_browser
```

Here is the full code:

```
function detail_metagenome_microbe_grafik($trflp_code, $metacode) {
    $total = '(select count(*) from tb_browser)';
    $query = $this->db->select('concat(round((100*count(*))/'.$total.',0),"%") as data_percentage')
                  ->from('tb_browser')
                  ->group_by('browser')
                  ->get();      
    return $query->result_array();  
}
```

Comment: Thank @Tim Biegeleisen,  it displays the results but the value 0.00xx how to round off the value such as 10% or 20%

Comment: Well if you're rounding to the nearest whole number there could be some rounding error present.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$query = $this->db->select('browser, (count(*) / <total_rec_count>) *100 as data_percentage')
                  ->from('tb_browser')
                  ->group_by('browser')
                  ->get();      
return $query->result_array();
```

Comment: thank you for answer, but how to round off the value?

Comment: `$this->db->select('browser, concat(round(((count(*) / <total_rec_count>) * 100),0),'%') as data_percentage` - is working for same scenario.

Comment: I was trying to copy as paste the query part. You need to complete the codeigniter syntax... updated with full syntax  `$this->db->select('browser, concat(round(((count(*) / <total_rec_count>) * 100),0),"%") as data_percentage')`

Answer (score 0):

need to get the actual total to do the calculation

```
$query = $this->db->select('browser, (count(*) / (select count(*) from tb_browser)) *100 as data_percentage')
```

I'm a bit rusty at mysql and haven't got an instance handy... unfortunately mysql doesn't support OVER()

Comment: Thanks @Brian Ramsey that's very helpful.

Comment: No problems.. might get a bit more data than you want (decimal places) could wrap the calculation in a floor() function to round to nearest integer :)